# Algebraic computation and interpretation of X(X^T) - I

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projective-geometry

Just stuck on the last part of a problem, and the solution gives that:

If $[C(X)]^2$ = $X(X^T)-I$, X a 3x1 column vector, unit length, then I know that $XX^T$ is the orthogonal projection of vectors onto X.

But, why is $C(X)^4$ = $I-XX^T$?  The solution doesn't explain, so I tried to work it out by squaring $[C(X)]^2$, but I'm not getting that answer.

Also, the solution interprets $I-XX^T$ as the orthogonal projection of vectors onto $X^\perp$.  Is this sort of like the range of $XX^T$ contains all the vectors projected onto X, and then 1 - this range space is "everything else", namely the vectors in $X^\perp$?  If my intuition is correct here, how do I make it precise?  Or, perhaps it is just a definition and doesn't need any further clarification.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to look at things: let $U$ be a matrix with columns $u_1 = X,u_2,u_3$ so that the columns of $U$ form an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$.  Note that $UU^T = I$. We can write
$$
X^TX= U\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}U^T
$$
To show this, try the block matrix-multiplication
$$
\pmatrix{u_1&u_2&u_3} \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}\pmatrix{u_1^T\\u_2^T\\u_3^T}
$$

furthermore,
$$
I = UIU^T
$$
it follows that
$$
I - X^TX = U\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}U^T - U\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}U^T\\
= U\left[\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1} - \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}\right]U^T\\
= U\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}U^T \\
= u_2u_2^T + u_3u_3^T
$$

Comment: I actually used the fact that the projection matrix, squared, is still the same matrix, so I accept the algebraic manipulations now.  I would just need to make the idea of I-XX^T having range space = all the vectors perpendicular to X a little more precise.  I'm not sure if that's implied in your solution?  Thanks, @Omnomnomnom..

Comment: The key is that $u_2,u_3$ is an orthonormal basis of the space perpendicular to $X$, $I - XX^T = u_2u_2^T + u_3u_3^T$ is the projection onto the space of vectors perpendicular to $X$.

Comment: does X^TX-I have the same range as I-XX^T?  Your last computation starts with X^TX-I.  Thanks,@Omnomnomnom.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, fixed it.  Note that $XX^T - I = -(I - XX^T)$.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much for the help, @Omnomnomnom.  Have a great night :)